# Does the string functions in DB2 work on a limited ASCII character set?

Tags: db2, string-formatting

In a program I have used a function RPAD() to format data coming from DB2 db.
In one instance the value was Ãmber. The following function:

```
RPAD('Ãmber',10,' ')
```

gives 9 characters only.
The ASCII value of 'Ã' is 195. I am not able to understand the reason for this behaviour.
Could someone share their experience.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, DB2 will consider the length of Ã to be 2, likely because it is counting bytes rather than characters.

```
values(LENGTH('Ãmber'))
 6
```

You can override it for [LENGTH](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000818.html) and many other functions

```
values(LENGTH('Ãmber', CODEUNITS16))
 5
```

Unfortunately, [RPAD](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053530.html) does not take a parameter like this. I'm guessing this might be because the function was added for Oracle compatibility rather than on its own merits.

You could write your own RPAD function as a stored procedure or UDF, or just handle it with a CASE statement if this is the only place where you need it.

Comment: could you please tell in a progrmming langauge like c# i am getting the correct length for the string. Is it something to do with the difference in the character encoding used? Can this problem be solved by having the proper character encoding in DB?

Comment: The programming language isn't relevant if you want DB2 to do the padding. I don't think you can solve this by messing with character encodings. Changing the encoding would fix a character not being recognized or being corrupted, but DB2 is clearly recognizing Ã as Ã.